# NgRx Effects catchError never start

Tags: angular, authentication, ngrx, angularfire

Why my loginFailure actions doesn't work? When I pass incorrect password loginSuccess action is fire and user variable include error data.

login is Promise from firebase auth.

```
        ofType(authActions.login),
        switchMap(creditionals => from(this.userService.login(creditionals.email, creditionals.password)).pipe(
                map( (user: User) => authActions.loginSuccess({ user })),
                catchError(error => of(authActions.loginFailure({ error })))
            )
        )
    ), {
        dispatch: true
    });

actions

export const login = createAction(
    '[Auth] Login',
    props<{ email: string, password: string  }>()
);

export const loginSuccess = createAction(
    '[Auth] Login Success',
    props<{ user: User }>()
);

export const loginFailure = createAction(
    '[Auth] Login Failure',
    props<{ error: any }>()
);
```

Comment: Can you show the actions?

Comment: @MikeOne actions added above